Does the light reflected from the screen at the end of a double slit experiment interfere with the results?
I'm a little confused about the double slit experiment.
I am wondering if there have been any experiments testing whether the light reflected from the screen, at the end of a double slit experiment causes interference.
Would the same pattern be present, if the screen was changed after each individual photon? Any answers would be appreciated, thanks!

there are many double slit experiments that do not involve a screen and photons , but complicated detection  ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment )  equipment.

I'm confused because you're talking about light and also electrons.

search this site and my id for many answers on DSE
